# Unable to analyse project with SonarQube

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, eclipse-kepler

I want to analyse project with SonarQube
while doing this it gives me a error message saying

> Error during execution of Sonar
>   Error status [command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Users\qfrg\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-runner-impl7722306846094038579.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain C:\Users\qfrg\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-project6654886318444556353.properties]: 1

In the console log i see this :

> Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: The plugin javascript is not supported with Java 1.6.0_18
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/plugins/javascript/JavaScriptPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

I installed plugins for findbugs, checkstyle, PMD and M2Eclipse successfully before installing sonarqube, but after installing sonarqube, when i tried to add them again they say that

> Unable to connect to repository http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update/compositeContent.xml
>   Connection to http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net refused

Please find my version and plugin details:
    java:

> java version "1.6.0_18"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

maven:

> Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 23:01:09+0530)
>   Maven home: C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.3-bin
>   Java version: 1.6.0_18, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
>   Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

```
and
```

> SonarQube Server 4.5.4
>      Eclipse : Kepler Service Release 2

And i am using TFS as source control
Where am i going wrong ?
Is this the problem with java version ? As, I have seen in some sites that it worked for them when upgraded to 1.7 version of java

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Major.minor version 51.0 means J2SE 7, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/136363) for a more thorough explanation on version numbers. Basically this means it's not compatible with J2SE 6.0, which you're trying to use it with. Try upgrading your Java version or getting an older version of SonarQube and/or the Javascript plugin.

Comment: SonarQube 4.5.4 server needs based on different plugins Java 1.7. Downgrading does not work. Furthermore don't use Maven 3.0.3 anymore...

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/end-of-java-5-support-at-runtime-for-sonar-platform/) and [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-HardwareRequirements) is it that i cant use sonar with java 1.6.0_18 and also can i know the reason for > Furthermore don't use Maven 3.0.3 anymore @khmarbaise

Comment: I upgraded my java version to 7 and this time the issue is like after installing sonarQube 3.4, i am not able to open eclipse marketplace anymore and it gives me the following error in the error log

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot install remote marketplace locations: HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
 at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:101)
................
............

Comment: I tried adding **-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4** to eclipse.ini
after this opening eclipse markeplace says : 
**"Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Read timed out"**

Comment: Done
added **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** to my eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the [Requirements documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements), Java 7 at least is required to run SonarQube server and SonarQube analyses.

You are using a Java 6 virtual machine, this is why you get those error messages.